# Rally .NET Toolkit - create object with rank

Tags: rally

I'm trying to create a Rally object (defect or user story) with a rank, using the .NET API. Does anyone have an example or a link to some documentation that might be useful? I have not found any way to invoke the rankBelow and rankAbove end-points from the .NET Toolkit. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET toolkit does not have this functionality built in. It's a missing feature and I submitted a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

As of v3.1.1 this is now implemented!  Create and Update both now have an overload which accepts a NameValueCollection of additional parameters to be included in the query string.

http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/html/1ed8c970-1308-7e30-6039-fd33432bb5c1.htm

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)